# CF CLI Command: apply-manifest and its behaviour

Tags: cloud-foundry

I came across CF CLI command `apply-manifest` in few places in the CF [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/sidecars.html).

When I try to read the documentation of this command in CF CLI ( v7 for me); I saw this

```
cf help apply-manifest
NAME:
   apply-manifest - Apply manifest properties to a space
```

This command looks little **different** compared to the other commands that I learnt so far. I understand , normally `manifest` is a descriptor for **an** `app`. However `apply-manifest` is applying manifest properties to a **space** .

So this command is applied to the *whole* **space**

Could anyone help me to understand

- what is the usecase where one might apply manifest properties to the **space** ( not to an app)
- what is the implication of this command on apps which are already deployed and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the usecase where one might apply manifest properties to the space ( not to an app)

I agree the description is a little confusing at first. To explain, you apply a manifest to the space because your manifest can reference multiple applications. The manifest itself will tell the cli which applications to update.

The top-level block in the YAML is a list of applications. It contains configuration settings for one or more applications.

```
---
version: 1
applications:
...
```

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-apps

> what is the implication of this command on apps which are already deployed and running

It's my understanding that this command functions very similar to `cf push` except that it's not pushing new code & it's not going to restage your application.

Thus it would be a way for you to update the env, bound services, processes, etc.. for one or more applications in an efficient way and bypass the restage.

In terms of the impact on your application, I'd expect it to function in the same way as setting that metadata directly. i.e. if you `cf set-env` or use `apply-manifest` to set an env variable, it's still going to require you to restart your application for that env variable to take effect.

Comment: this explanation makes sense